# Can't post to another site with php code

Tags: php

I have a problem with my php code.

This is my code:

```
<?php if($this->template->params->get("blast2", 1) == 1) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->template->params->get("blast2_link", ''); ?>"
class="social_blast" id="social_blast2" target="_blank">Blast site</a><?php endif; ?>
```

What I need to do is get the URL of the current page along with the title and post this to another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work fine:

```
<?php if($this->template->params->get("blast2", 1) == 1) : ?>
<a href="http://blast-site.com/submit?Url=<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]?>&title=<?=mainframe->getPageTitle()?>&no_mobile=1"
class="social_blast" id="social_blast2" target="_blank">Blast site</a><?php endif; ?>
```